# How to validate any file upload on server side in GRAILS controller?

Tags: grails, groovy

**My Code In gsp:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <g:form controller="some_controller" action="some_action" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input id="Resume" type="file" name="Resume" />
    </g:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**My controller code :**

```
def candidate = new Candidate(params)
MultipartHttpServletRequest mhsr = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request
MultipartFile candResume = mhsr.getFile('candResume')

if(userService.fileExt().contains(candResume.getContentType()))
 {
 candidate.candResume=candResume.getBytes() //Converting a file into bytes
 if(candidate.validate())
   {
   if(candidate.save(flush: true,failOnError: true))
    {
     println "++++++++++Candidate Success+++++++++++++"
     flash.candSuccess="Candidate successfully added."
    }
   }
   else{
     println "====Sorry Candidate Upload Failed===="
     flash.candFail="Candidate failure."
   }
}
```

**My service code :**

```
public List fileExt(){
        List fileExtensions=["doc", "docx", "pdf", "rtf"]
        println "--------in the service----------"
        return fileExtensions
    }
```

The thing is in **if(userService.fileExt().contains(candResume.getContentType()))**
the service is getting invoked but not retiurning anything the upload is getting failed without any message. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do something like this :

In controller:

```
def userService
def candidate = new Candidate(params)
  def resumeFile = request.getFile('candResume')

  if (userService.allowedExtension(resumeFile)) {
    blablabla
```

in Service:

```
Class UserService {

  def allowedExtension (aFile) {
    List fileExtensions=["doc", "docx", "pdf", "rtf"]
    println "--------in the service----------"
    def extension = aFile?.originalFilename?.substring(aFile?.originalFilename?.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    return fileExtensions.contains(extension); // if you rely on the actual file name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use mimetype instead extension of files.

Here you find how to get the mimetype of a file using Tika: [Getting MimeType subtype with Apache tika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137634/getting-mimetype-subtype-with-apache-tika)