# Apache Tika correctly detect mime type in the new version

Tags: java, mime-types, apache-tika

I'm trying to detect MIME types of the files by their byte content. I'm using `Apache Tika`. The problem was that when detecting `.docx` or `.xlsx` files, Tika was giving strange types like `application/x-tika-ooxml` and I didn't find anywhere the complete list of these special Tika types so I can map them to existing MIME types.

But [following this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137634/getting-mimetype-subtype-with-apache-tika) helped me, and I was able to get the correct MIME types like `application/msword` instead of Tika ones. But in order to do that I needed to downgrade the version from latest to one of the older ones (1.28.1 instead of 2.3.0), but it's probably not the best approach, I suppose.

So my question is: what is the correct way for the newest version of how to detect MIME types? I think you should be able to do that in the newest versions too. I simply used the code from the question:

```
 TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
 Detector detector = config.getDetector();
 TikaInputStream stream = TikaInputStream.get(fileOrStream);
 Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
 metadata.add(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, filenameWithExtension);
 MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(stream, metadata);
```

But the problem with the new version is that there's no `Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY` anymore. I also added the same version of `tika-parsers` dependency, is that necessary in the new version?

Comment: Pass Tika the filename, and ensure you have the office parsers on your classpath

Comment: @Gagravarr, do you have any code examples?

Comment: See https://tika.apache.org/2.3.0/detection.html#Ways_of_triggering_Detection